# most efficient solution for this array ruby and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

My question is:

**is there some most efficient solution for this code in ruby on rails and mongoid odm?**

```
messages_without_responses = Message.all.select{|message| message.sender == current_user || message.receiver == current_user}
messages = Array.new
messages_without_responses.each do |m|
  if m.message_responses.count > 0 
   messages << m
  else
   messages << m if m.receiver_id == current_user.id && m.place_receiver == "inbox"
  end
end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you like what you've written?

Comment: I like, is working fine :D, but I want to know if it can be done in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many records are in your DB, but if the number might get large, you are better filtering out the records you want at the DB level rather than in Ruby. Hence the SQL conditions on `Message.all` (you'll have to translate as necessary to make this usable with Mongoid; I've never used it before).

```
ms = Message.all(:conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id])
```

The rest is not bad, but you could make it more concise:

```
ms.select { |m| m.message_responses.count > 0 || (m.receiver == current_user &&  m.place_receiver == "inbox")}
```